# css3 transistions question

Tags: css

I'm playing about with transitions in webkit. I'm transitioning the dimensions of a div on hover and I've noticed that the width is animated from the top and the left of the div....I really want it to grow from the center of the div....is this possible?

Comment: `margin: 0 auto;` to make the div center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look at `transform: scale` instead of `width` and `height`. The transform property lets you specify a origin for the transform, and it defaults to the center.

I set up a jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Tb7sm/ (obviously, you'll need a webkit browser).

Comment: To add, if you want width and height to scale at different values, use scaleX() and scaleY()